# How can I run two makefile targets such that the second uses the first's variables?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am writing a makefile that has multiple targets for architectures and build types. When I call make I would like to be able to pass it two targets such as:

```
make x86 debug
```

Where the architecture target sets variables to be used by the build target. An architecture target might look like this:

```
.PHONY: x86
x86: NAME_PREFIX = x86_64_Linux
x86: TARGET_TRIPLE = x86_64-pc-linux-elf
x86: CC = gcc
x86: CFLAGS += -fomit-frame-pointer
```

First issue: If I run the two targets, make skips the first target since it does nothing but set variables.

```
$ make x86 debug
make: Nothing to be done for `x86'.
```

Second issue: Even if it would run the first target, my understanding is that the values won't be retained when make starts running the second target anyway.

For now, I'm using targets that set variables and add the build type target as a prerequisite at the end of the target body, but I would end up needing a target for every combination of architecture and build type.

```
.PHONY: x86_debug
x86_debug: NAME_PREFIX = x86_64_Linux
x86_debug: TARGET_TRIPLE = x86_64-pc-linux-elf
x86_debug: CC = gcc
x86_debug: CFLAGS += -fomit-frame-pointer
x86_debug: debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is better.  But you don't need a target for every combination, if you use a consistent naming scheme, and use wildcard targets:

```
.PHONY: x86_% arm_% # etc
.PHONY: %_debug %_optimised # etc

x86_%: NAME_PREFIX = x86_64_Linux
x86_%: TARGET_TRIPLE = x86_64-pc-linux-elf
x86_%: CC = gcc
x86_%: CFLAGS += -fomit-frame-pointer

arm_%: NAME_PREFIX = ARM_LINUX
arm_%: TARGET_TRIPLE = arm-linux-eabi
arm_%: CC = arm-linux-gcc


%_debug: CFLAGS += -g

%_optimised: CFLAGS += -O3
```

Comment: I modified my makefile accordingly but make doesn't seem to recognize % as a wildcard character. I'm using GNU Make 3.82.

Comment: I'm sure I've done something like that before.  You did include a target with rules, right?

Comment: Yes, the build targets have rules. I'm simply getting `make: *** No rule to make target 'x86_debug'.  Stop.` despite having the target `x86_%` as in the example and a `%_debug` target that calls the compiler.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had an additional target `clean` which I changed to `%_clean` so I could use it in place of my build type target. My `%_debug` target runs `clean` before compiling, so I changed the prerequisite to `_clean`. The problem is that the stem can't be a zero-length string, so `_clean` doesn't match `%_clean`. I would have thought make would give me a more helpful error like "No rule to make target _clean required by %_debug" or something like that.

Comment: An error like that doesn't quite make sense.  A pattern is a hint about one possible way to build a target.  You can have lots of patterns that could be used to build the same target (consider `%.o` as a pattern target...!) so if a given pattern doesn't match, make can't say that it's an error.  It goes to the next one.  Only after no patterns match can make conclude that no rule exists to build a given target.  It can't spit out errors for each prerequisite that couldn't be built for each pattern rule that matches a target.